# Rake equivalent of make -j (--jobs)

Tags: ruby, multithreading, rake, rakefile

The `make` commands allows a `-j` (`--jobs`) options documented as such:

```
-j [jobs], --jobs[=jobs]
     Specifies the number of jobs (commands) to run simultaneously.  If there is more than one -j  option,
     the  last  one  is effective.  If the -j option is given without an argument, make will not limit the
     number of jobs that can run simultaneously.
```

In a day and age where even cell phones have multiple cores and/or processors, I want my build systems to handle multithreaded processing.

What is the best way to set up `rake` so I can ensure up to 3 tasks are running at all times?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, rake allows the jobs to run in parallel. To set up the level of parallelism, use `-j` switch. From `rake --help`:

```
-j, --jobs [NUMBER] Specifies the maximum number of tasks to execute in parallel. (default is number of CPU cores + 4)
```

But, the job itself must be written as a multitask, not a task. So the instead of defining the task like:

```
namespace :mynamespace  do
  desc "description"
  task task_name: :environment do
    your_code
  end
end
```

use multitask:

```
namespace :mynamespace  do
  desc "description"
  multitask task_name: :environment do
    your_code
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a blog post about rake [MultiTask](http://devblog.avdi.org/2014/04/29/rake-part-7-multitask/), but it supports the `-j` parameter as `-m` for parallelization.